# Json serializer different json name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a relationship between 2 elements. Basically, I have posts & categories.

In my approach I have 2 controllers:

`PostsController` with `index, show, update, destroy & *categories*`

`CategoriesController` with `index`

When I wanna modify the categories, I do a `POST` to the `/post/:post_id/categories`. And everything works ok. But the answer I wanna return is the categories of my post, just categories. So, I do:

```
render json: @post.categories, 
       each_serializer: CategorySerializer
```

And it work ok. But the answer I receive in the json is:

```
posts: [{id:1, title:'Category 1'}, {id:2, title:'Category 2'}]
```

But the desired output should be:

```
categories: [{id:1, title:'Category 1'}, {id:2, title:'Category 2'}]
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
categories = @post.categories.map { |c| CategorySerializer.new(c) }
render json: { categories: categories }
```

Comment: I use this as a guide. But I didn't use your first line. I only change: 

from: `render json: @post.categories` 

to: `render {categories: @post.categories}`

I need the previous line for something in theory? Or can I use my workaround? 

Thanks so much! It works! But I wanna know the reason of the first line (or if I can use the workaround without problem) after mark as accepted :)

Comment: The reason of the first line is to change the root key, which takes from the`@post` variable, by default. You can also check [`How to add root key`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_root_key.md#how-to-add-root-key) and [`Overriding the root key`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md#overriding-the-root-key), but I found easier use a hack like in my answer.